# Unable to authenticate on Crypto.com API C# REST API

Tags: crypto.com-exchange-api

Crypto.com offers an [API](https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/spot/index.html) where supposedly you could access their exchange platform. However, their documentation is extremely poor and inaccurate in terms of C# examples. I am unable to authenticate my REST calls using C#.

For all the `private` (account related) calls you need to [sign your requests](https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/spot/index.html#digital-signature) by adding a `sig` parameter to your payload JSON.

A simplified version of my code that calculates the `sig` parameter for the [private/get-account-summary](https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/spot/index.html#private-get-account-summary) method looks like this (.net50):

```cs
private static string GetSignature()
{
    string sigPayload = "private/get-account-summary" + 1 + API_KEY + "currencyCRO" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

    var hash = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(API_SECRET));
    var computedHash = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sigPayload));

    return Convert.ToHexString(computedHash);
}
```

, while the request which makes use of this signature looks like this:

`POST https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/get-account-summary`

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "method": "private/get-account-summary",
    "api_key": "[api_key]",
    "params": {
        "currency": "CRO"
    },    
    "nonce": "1615048530368",
    "sig": "1A7C7183CAF2E71F7F7DAB6A5C7F74319E692F2638710292BDB4FDFAC6C864D6"
}
```

As far as I know, I've correctly applied their algorithm for creating the signature and also used the correct parameters to call the method in question (https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/spot/index.html#private-get-account-summary). However, the response that I get tells me that I'm doing something wrong:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "method": "private/get-account-summary",
    "code": 10002,
    "message": "UNAUTHORIZED"
}
```

I'm starting to have doubts that the API even works for `private` methods. Their support is awful and sent me to read the documentation again. I would appreciate any help in any language. If I at least hear that somebody else did it in another language I could use their example to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line in the sample needs to be changed like this:

```cs
Convert.ToHexString(computedHash).ToLower();
```

In the end I followed my own advice and tried to call the service using one of the other sample languages. When I used JavaScript (which had a way better sample in the documentation) I've noticed the the resulting `sig` was lower case.